# Problems converting a string date to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have this string date:

```
2014-04-21T07:55:13Z
```

when I convert that to NSDate I have the hour like 6:55... 1 hours less. WHY?

This is the code I am using to convert:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

`newDate` is now `2014-04-21 06:55:13 +0000` !!!???

what is wrong?

NOTE: That one hour less would make sense if the date was my local time (GMT+1) being converted to GMT. But if that Z is zero offset ( = GMT) the date is already GMT.

Comment: Have a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033892/converting-date-of-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code is wrong. using this code:-

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2014-04-21T07:55:13Z";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

 NSLog(@" date log %@",date); //2014-04-21 02:25:13 +0000 output

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"string %@",dateStr);  //2014-04-21T07:55:13Z output
```

but `NSLog` of `NSDATE` is not output correct according to this [NSDate Format outputting wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229024/nsdate-format-outputting-wrong-date) so your code is right.

> The NSDate doesn't know anything about formatting (just date information), and the NSDateFormatter doesnt really know anything about dates, just how to format them. So you have to use methods like -stringFromDate: for know that is current or not  to actually format the date for pretty human-readable display.

```
NSLog(@" date is %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: my date contains a Z, meaning that it is already GMT0, now can NSDate convert to GMT a date that is already GMT. I first thought NSDate was considering my local timezone that is GMT+1 but then I verified that when it converts that date that is already GMT to GMT, it subtracts one hour. In other words, it is converting a GMT date to GMT by converting it to GMT-1!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are right by mysterious ways  I verified now that you should not **EVER** – and I cannot put that bold enough – trust NSDate for anything.